# Unable to load WKWebView into containerView

Tags: wkwebview

I am trying to load a web view inside a container view which is basically a UIView inside the main View.But somehow its not loading.

```
var urlString : String!
var termsAndConditionsWebView : WKWebView!

@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    //self.termsAndConditionsWebView.frame = containerView.frame
    //self.termsAndConditionsWebView.sizeToFit()
    self.termsAndConditionsWebView = WKWebView()
    containerView = termsAndConditionsWebView
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com.sg")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    termsAndConditionsWebView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: I am able to load the webView now but it doesn't scale properly to fit the entire containerView. Need help.

Comment: override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        termsAndConditionsWebView = WKWebView()
        termsAndConditionsWebView.frame = self.containerView.frame
        termsAndConditionsWebView.sizeToFit()
        self.containerView.addSubview(termsAndConditionsWebView)

    }

Comment: Solution:      override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        let wkWebConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()

        termsAndConditionsWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.containerView.frame.size.width, self.containerView.frame.size.height), configuration: wkWebConfig)

        termsAndConditionsWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        containerView.addSubview(termsAndConditionsWebView)
    
    }